Chip Erase verification on AtTiny3217
I'm trying to write software to program an AtTiny3217 via UDPI, but I'm stuck when it comes to performing the Chip Erase step.
In the datasheet, it says


Enter the Chip Erase key by using the KEY instruction. See Table 33-5 for the CHIPERASE signature.
Optional: Read the Chip Erase (CHIPERASE) bit in the ASI Key Status (UPDI.ASI_KEY_STATUS) register to see that the key is successfully activated.
Write the signature to the Reset Request (RSTREQ) bit in the ASI Reset Request (UPDI.ASI_RESET_REQ)
register. This will issue a System Reset.
Write 0x00 to the ASI Reset Request (UPDI.ASI_RESET_REQ) register to clear the System Reset.
Read the NVM Lock Status (LOCKSTATUS) bit from the ASI System Status (UPDI.ASI_SYS_STATUS) register.
The chip erase is done when LOCKSTATUS bit is ‘0’. If the LOCKSTATUS bit is ‘1’, return to step 5.
Check the Chip Erase Key Failed (ERASE_FAILED) bit in the ASI System Status (UPDI.ASI_SYS_STATUS) register to verify if the chip erase was successful.
If the ERASE_FAILED bit is ‘0’, the chip erase was successful.


The problem arises in step 7.  If we look at the information about the ASI_SYS_STATUS register a few pages on, you'll see no mention of an ERASE_FAILED bit.

So the question remains, how can I verify that an erase is successful, ideally without reading in the entire flash memory space?
I've found a different AVR datasheet that lists bit 6 of that register as ERASE_FAILED, can anyone verify that that is the case on the AtTiny3217?
I've tried creating a ticket with Microchip Support, but I am currently unable to log in (I created a ticket about that, and I'm waiting on a response).
I've also checked the errata, but there's no mention of that register in there at all.

I just realized I can create a ticket using a different email address, so I might be answering this myself once Microchip gets back to me.

I have heard back on my ticket with Microchip support.
Apparently, mention of the ERASE_FAILED bit in the datasheet was a mistake, the bit is not visible to the programmer.

Looking at other datasheets also including UPDI, the ERASE_FAILED bit exists, and is bit 6 in the ASI_SYS_STATUS register. My guess would be that the bit is present on the 3217 as well, but was erronously left out of the datasheet. However, only way to know for sure would be to wait for an official response.
EDIT: See the other response.
